# How to get only the occurrences with more than one value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table in mysql:

```
transcription_id |  speaker |   sentence
---------------------------------------------------------
1918                  1         'hello, good morning'
1918                  2         'how are you'
```

The `speaker` column can only be 1 or 2, `transcription_id` is the key of the dataset, so it is unique.

The normal case is for one `transcription_id` to have both speakers (1 and 2), because a conversation is usually between 2 people, but there are cases with only one speaker like transcription_id = 1921:

```
transcription_id |  speaker |   sentence
--------------------------------------------------------
1920                  1         'hello, good morning'
1920                  2         'hi!'
**1921                1         'good night' <----------------------**
1922                  1         'hello, good morning'
1922                  2         'buenas notches!'
```

How can I select only the sentences that have both speaker?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE t.speaker in (1, 2) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM table t1 
              WHERE t1.transcription_id = t.transcription_id AND t1.speaker <> t.speaker
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put them in one row using aggregation:

```
select transaction_id, min(sentence), max(sentence)
from t
group by transaction_id;
```

This puts the values in a single row.  If you want individual rows, then Yogesh's answer is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

There's a standard SQL clause `HAVING` allowing to filter groups by aggregated values.
In this case you should use `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` to get what is required.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM transcription_table
 WHERE (transcription_id, speaker)
             IN (
                  SELECT transcription_id, speaker
                    FROM transcription_table
                    GROUP BY transcription_id, speaker
                   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

Depending on what are you looking for, it's possible to vary counting.

For instance, use `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SPEAKER) > 1` to exclude repeatable speakers.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `transcription_id`s with grouping by transcription_id and the condition `having count(distinct speaker) = 2`:

```
select *
from tablename
where transcription_id in (
  select transcription_id 
  from tablename
  group by transcription_id
  having count(distinct speaker) = 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data in the table do not contain the same `speaker` twice for the same `transcription_id` then you can use the following MySQL query

`SELECT *  FROM speakers 
WHERE transcription_id IN (
SELECT transcription_id 
FROM speaker
group by transcription_id having count(*) = 2);`